# How to fix ' Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view, ternary-operator

I'm working on MVC project and I'm looping some values, and sometimes ome of those values is null:

[image]

What can I write and how can I write ?? operator or whatever in case `@Item.User_class.User1.Nickname` is null to set some default values.

Code:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.nextClassesList)
{ 
    <tr class="@item.Status">
        <td>@item.ClassDate</td>
        <td>@item.User_Class.User1.NickName ? @item.User_Class.User.NickName   </td>
        <td>@item.User_Class.ClassType.ClassTypeName.Name (@item.User_Class.ClassType.ClassTypeName.Time min)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

So this line is problem:

```
<td>@item.User_Class.User1.NickName ? @item.User_Class.User.NickName   </td>


<td>@item.User_Class.User1.NickName </td> Is null sometimes...
```

Comment: Why don't you create a flattened view model, populate the new view model in your controller action method and do all the null checks there instead of in the view? Currently you've got up to 3 levels of null checks to do in your view which will get ugly.

Comment: @Fran I've received this project from my friend. I need to fix this until I create new solution for this issue, that's reason why I'm asking how this might be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every property that is an object under your @item, you need to perform null checks down to a simple property level

```
(@item.User_Class == null) ? string.Empty : (@item.User_Class.User1 == null) ? (@item.User_Class.User == null) ? string.Empty : @item.User_Class.User.NickName :  @item.User_Class.User1.NickName
```

you need to also check the User object as well as it could also be null.

```
(@item.User_Class == null) ? string.Empty : (@item.User_Class.ClassTypeName == null) ? string.Empty : @item.User_Class.ClassTypeName.Name
```

so in your example

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.nextClassesList)
{ 
    <tr class="@item.Status">
        <td>@item.ClassDate</td>
        <td>(@item.User_Class == null) ? string.Empty : (@item.User_Class.User1 == null) ? (@item.User_Class.User == null) ? string.Empty : @item.User_Class.User.NickName :  @item.User_Class.User1.NickName</td>
...
}
```

Syntax may be a little off, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks! Can you post also example with editing my example (with for loops etc included). Thanks one more time

Answer (score 1):

You can use the null conditional ,available in C# version 6.0 and above:

@item?.User_Class?.ClassTypeName?.Name

Comment: Exactly.  it's null checks all the way down.

Comment: or the old way             (item.User_Class == null)
                    ? string.Empty
                    : (item.User_Class.ClassTypeName == null) ? string.Empty : item.User_Class.ClassTypeName.Name;

Comment: @Fran I'm talking about item.User_Class.User1.NickName, but whatever :D Can you please post example as answer so I might accept it because you'r the first one who came to this question